# Schema.NET HowTo item cannot add more than one step

Tags: c#, .net, seo, google-schemas

I've been trying to use Schema.NET to generate HowTo schema on certain articles. I have not been able to use this because I can only add a single step to the HowTo element. Google validation says I need at least 2 steps. Google samples show a step array, but again, I can only add a single step using Schema.NET.HowTo class.

```
var schema = new HowTo()
{
   Name = "How to tie make pie",
   Description = "If you want to make pie...",
   Step = //This property's type is Values<ICreativeWork, IHowToSection, IHowToStep, string>
};
```

For reference, here are Google's examples: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/how-to#standard

Any idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I just look closer at the Values object and noticed you can use an array of IHowToStep object.